# how to remove the whitespace in input field of symfony form type?

Tags: php, symfony

how to remove the white spaces in input field of Symfony form type?

I want to to throw an error when the user put only white spaces in inputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should use `trim` in your form type:

```
$builder
        ->add('title',null,[
            'required' => 'required',
            'trim' => true,
            ])
```

and in your entity add `@Assert\NotBlank` :

```
/**
 * @Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation\Versioned
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
```

Symfony will handle the rest.

Comment: In case someone else reads this...this method does indeed remove leading and trailing whitespace, but will not fix something with whitespace in the middle like "my string has spaces."